# Using UIPageViewController and making the view look like it's flapping

Tags: iphone, ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm wondering if there's a way to animate the very first view in `UIPageViewController` so that it looks like the one of the page corners is flapping a little bit? As if a little breeze bristles the pages when you first arrive on this particular screen.

This to add some sort of UI affordance to indicate that screen can be swiped. The content we're displaying with `UIPageViewController` doesn't take up the entire screen like a book does but would like to make it more obvious to the user that they can use gestures to navigate horizontally.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Nice question. Are you looking for more of an animation or will just a curl (like in the Maps app) suffice? If you want just a curl, you can create an image and put it in the correct spot.

Comment: It was too long for me to remember - but we tried to do this but found it very tedious to stop and play the built-in animation - instead we did a 5 image animation. Later in user testing users found it sufficient to understand how it would work.

Comment: r u looking like animation of book page?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look there: https://github.com/brow/leaves

This guy made a new ViewControllers / View class allowing this kind of animation.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about overlaying an animated GIF in the corner of the page bobbing about a bit, which you can then dismiss as soon as the user interacts with the page? (I know GIFs are a pain to work with on iOS, but it's certainly possible.)